# php function calls structure

Tags: php, function, structure

I have a problem with my current function call structure.

The structure is like this:
one file called "index.php" and another file call "function.php"

Inside function.php is just function after functions

function.php

```
<?php 
include 'settings.php';
date_default_timezone_set('Australia/Brisbane');

function one{
};

function two{
};
```

Index.php is just calling the functions from function.php file

Index.php

```
<?php
include 'include/functions.php';
$name = one():
?>
```

The advantage of this structure is when I saw the function has an error on index.php, I can just crt-f(find) in function.php and debug the function easily.

The other way around is cause me problem. I went through the function.php and saw some functions kinda doing the same things. I want to delete it but I don't know where is the function call form which pages. I have hundreds page on this website.

I want to make the code more tighter but I scare any change in function.php would break the website.

Yes, I can test the website after every change in function.php but to test the whole website for one function to be delete. It is time consuming. That's assume I test it correctly.

How would you guys handle this situation?

Many thx in advance ;)

Comment: 1) Have automatic tests that run after every change to make sure everything still works. 2) Use `ack` or `grep` to find all uses of a function before changing it.

Comment: Automatic tests! How can you do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With an [IDE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrated_development_environment) like [Zend Studio](http://www.zend.com/de/products/studio) or [Aptana](http://www.aptana.com/) you can search the usage of a function. If a function is not used anywhere, you can delete id whitout having problems (except you make function calls with variable or buildet function names). For more safety i suggest you to make functional tests for your projects with [PHPUnit](https://phpunit.de/) when you are going to modify/extend/delete code/functions.